# Magic mouse está pulando as seções quando faço o scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, mac

Então, quando uso um mouse normal, o scroll está correto, mas quando uso magic mouse, ele pula uma-duas seções. Como resolvo isso? Tentei adicionar um delay(100) quando o usuário tivesse usando MAC que até resolveu a questão, problema que o usuário diz que dá umas travadas (deve ser só a demora em fazer o scroll).

```
var pages = 8;
var currentpage = 1;

var nextpage = currentpage + 1; if (nextpage > pages) { nextpage = pages; }
var prevpage = currentpage - 1; if (prevpage < 1) { prevpage = 1; }
var animatingup = false;
var animatingdown = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeDiv();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
    resizeDiv();
    scrolltocurrent();
}

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    if(!clickInterview) {
        if (animatingup==true) { return; }
        if (animatingdown==true) { return; }
        nextpage = currentpage + 1; if (nextpage > pages) { nextpage = pages; }
        prevpage = currentpage - 1; if (prevpage < 1) { prevpage = 1; }

        var prevent = function() {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

        if (animatingup == false) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$("#page"+(nextpage)).offset().top+50) {
                if (nextpage > currentpage) {
                    var p2 = $("#page"+(nextpage));
                    var pageheight = p2.position().top;
                    animatingdown = true;
                    window.onwheel = function(){ return prevent(); };
                    if(navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('WIN') > -1)
                        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: pageheight }, 500, 'swing', function() { currentpage = nextpage; animatingdown = false; $('html, body').stop(); window.onwheel = function(){ return true; }});
                    else if(navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') > -1)
                        $('html, body').stop().delay(100).animate({ scrollTop: pageheight }, 500, 'swing', function() { currentpage = nextpage; animatingdown = false; $('html, body').stop(); window.onwheel = function(){ return true; }});
                    return prevent();
                }
            }
        }
        if (animatingdown == false) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop()<=$("#page"+(currentpage)).offset().top-50) {
                if (prevpage < currentpage) {
                    var p2 = $( "#page"+(currentpage) );
                    var pageheight = p2.position().top-$(window).height();
                    animatingup = true;
                    window.onwheel = function(){ return prevent(); };
                    if(navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('WIN') > -1)
                        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: pageheight }, 500, 'swing', function() { currentpage = prevpage; animatingup = false; $('html, body').stop(); window.onwheel = function(){ return true; }});
                    else if(navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') > -1)
                        $('html, body').stop().delay(100).animate({ scrollTop: pageheight }, 500, 'swing', function() { currentpage = prevpage; animatingup = false; $('html, body').stop(); window.onwheel = function(){ return true; }});                         
                    return prevent();
                }
            }
        }
        return prevent();
    }
});

function scrolltocurrent() {
    var p2 = $( "#page"+(currentpage) );
    var pageheight = p2.position().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: pageheight }, 900);
}

function resizeDiv() {
    vpw = $(window).width();
    vph = $(window).height();
    $('.page').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
}

$('html, body').scrollTop(0);
```

Live: http://www.maiconfurtado.com.br/themartec/start-interview.php

Comment: Acho que estás a fazer contas a mais para o evento `$(window).scroll(function(event) {` sem throttle. Isso é muito pesado para o browser. Podes explicar o que esse código deve fazer (a funcionalidade na página)?

Comment: Ela verifica se a página desce ou sobe e faz o scrollTop animado